# How to show/hide parts of the page based on a condition in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is my C# code for session expiry:

```
Session.Timeout = Convert.ToInt32(Application["SessionExpire"]);
if (Convert.ToBoolean(Request.QueryString["Expired"]) == true)
{
    txtMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    txtMsg.Text = "Session expired";
}
```

When the session expiry it is redirected to login page, however the logged in `userName` and `logout` option is still visible.  This has to be carried out in below script.

```
<p>
    <% if (oIdentity != null)
       { %>
        Welcome, <% if (oIdentity.LoginId > 0)
                    {
                        Response.Write(oIdentity.Display.LoginName + " - ");  %>  <a href="#" id="DoLogOut">LogOut</a>
        <% }
                    else
                    { %>
            Guest
        <% }
       } %>
</p>
```

I need to remove the userName and hide the logout options.  Is it possible?

Comment: I know ASP.NET MVC 4 has the option to check with `if(Request.IsAuthenticated)`. Do you have this as well?

Comment: This is definitely **not** Razor.

Comment: You should ask yourself why `oIdentity` is not null when you claim that the user has been logged-out.

Comment: The question is not about editing Razor, it is about authentication.

Comment: I removed the irrelevant "Razor" tag and changed your title to better fit the question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using forms authentication, you can sign the user out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If you are using Windows authentication, it is very tricky. You may be able to do it in IE, but not in other browsers.

If it's neither, then please clarify in the question.

Answer (score 0):

A very lazy attempt would be to re-perform the check in the page aswell, changing this line:

```
Welcome, <% if (oIdentity.LoginId > 0)
```

to this

```
Welcome, <% if (oIdentity.LoginId > 0 && Convert.ToBoolean(Request.QueryString["Expired"]) == false)
```